# add files to root and access it within Android Studio Project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, objectinputstream, objectoutputstream

in java you could add the file within the project so you could use it on any device, i.e if the file is "data.dat" in java I could put the file in the project root and write this line

```
try (ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("data.dat')))
```

unfortunately I couldn't do this in android studio can someone please explain

in Android Studio it always gives me FileNotFoundException, I even tried using the absolute path but it didn't work, any Idea on how to do it?

Comment: "In java you could simply put the file in the project and do this" -- it is unclear what you mean by "put the file in the project". Your code reads a file from the filesystem of the computer running the code, and that might not be the computer that has the project.

Comment: "How to put a .dat file in android studio" -- what do you mean by this? Do you mean that you wish to ship this `.dat` file as part of your app and be able to read in its contents on an Android phone? If so, put it in an `assets/` directory that is peer of `res/` and `src/` in your module, and use `getAssets().open(relativePath)` on a `Context` to get an `InputStream` on the content. `relativePath` is the path to your asset within `assets/`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I mean in java you could add the file within the project so you could use it on any device, i.e if the file is "data.dat" in java I could put the file in the project root and write this line        ` try (ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("data.dat')))`